# How to access /data/data/ folder of other apps?

Tags: android, root

I am developing an app for custom device.
My app run from `/system/priv-app` and i need access to modify data folder of other apps for some configurations. For doing this i need write access to `/data/data/other.app.package`.

So there is any solution?

Comment: The other apps must give permissions to their data, such as with a ContentProvider. Android protects the "internal" storage so that other apps cannot access it.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice my app is specially run at custom created Android device and i want to always run as root. because this app must manage all features of this device.

Comment: You can not run an app as root. You can only start processes with root permissions from within your app. But as you have control over the OS may be an app with system permissions (app signed with the OS key and installed in system folder) may be a better way the achieve what you want.

Comment: @Robert if i sign my app with OS key, can i access to /data/data?

Comment: I don't know, never wrote a system app. However this is the maximum permission your app can get. Root access from within an app is possible however on a custom system I would avoid it as it is a security breach. Alternatively you could implement a service (a daemon on Linux level) running with root permissions and use that from within your app. But you have to make sure only your app is authorized to do so.

Comment: @ramineftekhari Any updates regarding this?